# How to combine images from multiple folder into one with a counting number using python

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I am really looking for a solution to this problem. I have been generating frames from a python code which i end up having into different folders as shown below,

```
**folder names** swimming_0, swimming_1, noswimming_0, noswimming_1.

swimming_0       noswimming_0
frame0.jpg      frame0.jpg
frame1.jpg      frame1.jpg 
frame2.jpg      frame2.jpg

swimming_1       noswimming_1
frame0.jpg      frame0.jpg
frame1.jpg      frame1.jpg 
frame2.jpg      frame2.jpg
```

What i expect:

```
In a single folder

swimming_0_0.jpg
swimming_0_1.jpg
swimming_0_2.jpg
swimming_1_0.jpg
swimming_1_1.jpg
swimming_1_2.jpg
noswimming_0_0.jpg
noswimming_0_1.jpg
noswimming_0_2.jpg
noswimming_1_0.jpg
noswimming_1_1.jpg
noswimming_1_2.jpg

The steps we need is that: 
1. rename the images in each folder
2. combine the images
```

Python code used:

```
step1: renaming and adding incremental numbers
import os

folderpath = r'/swimming'
fileNumber = 1

for filename in os.listdir(folderpath):
os.rename(folderpath + '//' + filename, folderpath  +  "_" + str(fileNumber))
fileNumber +=1
```

Although this code works with my expectations for step 1 however I am looking for a more efficient way to do this. Could someone please help here.

Update:

It is also fine if we dont keep track of the filenames but atleast in that case i would expect the results to be.

```
swimming_0.jpg
swimming_1.jpg
swimming_2.jpg
swimming_3.jpg
swimming_4.jpg
swimming_5.jpg
noswimming_6.jpg
noswimming_7.jpg
noswimming_8.jpg
noswimming_9.jpg
noswimming_10.jpg
noswimming_11.jpg
```

Comment: how more efficient do you want this to be (EDIT: you could use processes but that is a bit overkill for the seemingly small amount of images you have to process)? I mean you could use `enumerate()` so that you don't have to keep track of `fileNumber` like you do now but that will reduce code by like 2 lines that don't even affect performance (I mean they do by like less than 0.0000001% or sth) but otherwise this is pertty short code already, also I don't see your attempts on combining those images since that IMO should really be the question because part1 of your code works already

Comment: Hi, but with enumerate, we will just get numbers but I would like to keep the prefix and please check my results I expect. Yes, in step 2 of combing files I do it manually but that is not a problem I can also do it in code. But my issue is with step 1.

Comment: ok, you will get numbers with enumerate ... can't you convert it to a string and concatenate with the prefix? I am guessing that it doesn't move files from those different folders to the one as you expect

Comment: @matiis , it is also fine if we could get my updated results as per your suggestion?.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you want to move files in separate folders to one you could try this:

First of you should have a structure like this:

```
from_here/
    + noswimming_0/
        + frame0.png
        + frame1.png
        + frame2.png
    + noswimming_1/
        + frame0.png
        + frame1.png
        + frame2.png
    + swimming_0/
        + frame0.png
        + frame1.png
        + frame2.png
    + swimming_1/
        + frame0.png
        + frame1.png
        + frame2.png
move_here/
script.py
```

---

`script.py:`

```py
import os


from_path = os.getcwd() + '/from_here'
to_path = os.getcwd() + '/move_here'

for folder in os.listdir(from_path):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(from_path, folder)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(from_path, folder, file), os.path.join(to_path, f'{folder}_{file}'))
```

This should now move the files from those separate folders to the one (obviously you could have more folders to move from or more files in those folders)